# Making GWT App crawlable when server is a REST Interface

Tags: gwt, rest, seo, web-crawler

I have a REST API and a GWT app as the front end. Can someone help me in making my GWT app crawlable because the documentation given by Google to make Ajax app crawlable is for a different server architecture??

I have a application which is decoupled as front-end and back-end. The front-end and the back-end are in the same domain but have different URLs.

For e.g. to access the front-end, the user may type "www.example.com#users" whereas within the application after getting the token "users", the application will call the REST API using a URL which is different from what the user typed such as "www.example.com/restAPI/users".

So in fact, for every token, we will have an application-level URL and a server-level URL which will always be different because to access the REST API, a different URL must be used.

So now, my server architecture is different from normal ajax application because if you push the application-level URL directly to the server without passing through the front-end, nothing will be obtained. THe front-end actually tailors the application-level URL and adapts to certain protocols, make the query to the REST API, get the result and update the UI on the front-end.

I need to make this app crawlable??

Comment: then google won't be indexing your GWT stuff but rather your rest backend :)

Comment: The REST API and the front end are in the same domain but have different URLs. First, I have an application level URL where the user click and the application state changes. For a particular token, the application may use the REST API URL to get further data. My issue is how to make the server understand the escape fragement??

Comment: aha, ok, i'll answer that one then, meanwhile please update your question

Comment: @milan, just check the question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you'd handle escape fragment on the serverside. The idea is to use a filter, intercept all urls (/*), and override `doFilter()`:

```
String queryString = req.getQueryString();

if ((queryString != null) && (queryString.contains("_escaped_fragment_="))) {
//    use htmlunit to fetch the rendered html and serve back
      WebClient webClient = getWebClient();
      String page = convertToUnescapedForm(queryString);
      String rendered = webClient.getPage(page);
      resp.getWriter().println(rendered);
...
} else {
     chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}
```

Comment: I've have tried to edit my question and explain it better, do you think the answer you gave me will work with the new things i've added, hope so :-)